# How to use default shortcuts for a different keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, atmelstudio

By default my Windows 8.1 system uses the German keyboard layout. Atmel Studio seems to have detected that during the installation, as some keyboard shortcuts use German characters (e.g. `ß`).

Due to easier access to all the relevant special characters (`[]{}/\`) I exclusively use the US keyboard layout for programming. I tried to find a way to convince Atmel Studio to change the default shortcuts to a specific language; I even changed the language of the IDE but without success.

I thought that there might be exported settings on the web which would allow me to import the English default keyboard shortcuts, but a google search was unsuccessful. The obvious solution would be to manually change the shortcuts but that's the brute force approach.

How can I use the default shortcuts for a different keyboard layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution should have been obvious. I needed to restart Atmel Studio after changing the language.